# Create an Excel file with the Excel interop class from SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I want to create an Excel file with the Excel interop class from the SQL Database. With SQL query, I had previously transferred the dataset into dataGridview. The result of the query is the data. However, I can't Print this data from the SQL database to Excel cells with the dataset.

```
private void linkLabel10_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
        {
            string fileTest = fbd.SelectedPath.ToString() + "\\"+ comboBox1.Text.Substring(0, comboBox1.Text.IndexOf("*") - 1) +"-"+ comboBox2.Text.Substring(0, comboBox2.Text.IndexOf("(") - 1) +"-"+ comboBox2.Text.Substring(comboBox2.Text.IndexOf("(") + 1, 10) + ".xlsx";
            MessageBox.Show(fileTest);
            if (File.Exists(fileTest))
            {
                File.Delete(fileTest);
            }

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select PersonelKodu= ztSinifEgitimiDurum.KisiID, İsim= dbo.cdCurrAcc.FullName, Katılım = CASE WHEN Katilim = 1 THEN 'Katıldı' ELSE 'Katılmadı' END, ztSinifEgitimiDurum.ID FROM dbo.ztSinifEgitimiDurum INNER JOIN dbo.cdCurrAcc ON cdCurrAcc.CurrAccCode = ztSinifEgitimiDurum.KisiID AND cdCurrAcc.CurrAccTypeCode = ztSinifEgitimiDurum.KisiTipiID WHERE AtamaID =" + AtamaIDBul(), baglan);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            Excel.Application Excel;
            Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet;
            Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook;

            Excel = new Excel.Application();
            excelWorkBook = Excel.Workbooks.Add();
            excelWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "some value";
            excelWorkSheet.Name = "Ali";

            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                    {
                        excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                    MessageBox.Show(table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName.ToString());
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
                        {
                            excelWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }

            //                   excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "some value";

            excelWorkBook.SaveAs(fileTest);
            excelWorkBook.Close();
            Excel.Quit();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are plenty of examples out there on converting a dataset to excel.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: What is the problem you get here? Did you debug? Is data set is populated with data when you are debugging. Or can't you save it to the target folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to fill your DataSet, add this line 
`da.Fill(ds);` after `DataSet ds = new DataSet();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to fill your sheet with values from a table:

```
  ws.Activate();
  foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
  {
            // Add column headers from the datatable 
            for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dt.Columns.Count; Idx++)
            {
                ws.Range["A1"].Offset[0, Idx].Value = dt.Columns[Idx].ColumnName;
            }

            // add data rows 
            for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dt.Rows.Count; Idx++)
            {  // hey I did not invent this line of code, I found it somewhere on CodeProject. 
                // It works to add the whole row at once 
                ws.Range["A2"].Offset[Idx].Resize[1, dt.Columns.Count].Value = dt.Rows[Idx].ItemArray;
            }
  ...
```

But you will have to add more worksheets for individual tables in case there is more than one table in your DataSet.

It is based [on this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141811/Database-to-Excel-Spreadsheet).